# Django Rest Framework - Router Register not working

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I'm using django rest framework to generate an api. In it I have two models, associated views and serializers. These are `beers` and `pours`. The `beers` api endpoint works as expected, but whenever I try to access the `pours` endpoint I get the following error:

`Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "pours-detail". You may have failed to include the related model in your API, or incorrectly configured the 'lookup_field' attribute on this field.`

I'm not quite sure what I am doing wrong, can someone point out the error?

**models.py**

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone


class Beers(models.Model):
    """
    Beers
    """
    # The unique id
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    # Timestamps
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=None, null=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(default=None, null=True)
    tap = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=None, null=True)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=None, null=True)
    abv = models.DecimalField(default=None, null=True, decimal_places=2, max_digits=3)
    style = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=None, null=True)
    score = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=None, null=True)
    tap_date = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=None, null=True)
    size = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=None, null=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        On save, update timestamps
        """
        # If the record does not currently exist in the database
        self.created_at = timezone.now()
        self.updated_at = timezone.now()

        return super(Beers, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'beers'
        index_together = [("tap", "tap_date")]


class Pours(models.Model):
    """
    Handles pours
    """
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    tap = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    amount = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=3, max_digits=19)
    date = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        On save, update timestamps
        """
        return super(Pours, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'pours'
        index_together = [("tap", "date")]
```

**views.py**

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer

from .serializers import *
from .models import *

import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class PoursView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    Handles pours
    """
    permission_classes = ()
    throttle_classes = ()
    authentication_classes = ()

    renderer_classes = (JSONRenderer,)

    queryset = Pours.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PoursSerialzier


class BeersView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    Handles beers
    """
    permission_classes = ()
    throttle_classes = ()
    authentication_classes = ()

    renderer_classes = (JSONRenderer,)

    queryset = Beers.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BeersSerialzier
```

**serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import *


class BeersSerialzier(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    queryset = Beers.objects.all()

    class Meta:
        model = Beers


class PoursSerialzier(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    queryset = Pours.objects.all()

    class Meta:
        model = Pours
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import include, patterns, url
from rest_framework import routers

import views

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'beers', views.BeersView)
router.register(r'pours', views.PoursView)

urlpatterns = [
    url('^', include(router.urls)),
]
```

Comment: remove the queryset initialization in serialization.  Provide some fields in the serializer.

Comment: I tried that according to @eyllanesc's answer and it resulted in the same error

Comment: Can you add some fields in the serializer ?

Comment: Id make sure at least that the register comes with a name, that could make things  much easier down the road. router.register(...name='beers')

I dont think that clears up the original issue though. Could you try calling those objects ViewSets? Like`PoursViewSet`? thats where I would start

Comment: Your `ViewSet`s are setup with list views (`queryset = ...all()`) but for some reason Pours thinks its being called as a detail view.

What is the exact url you are getting that error at? something like /pours/ or pours/1 ?